# Yii2 insert data to database from javascript generated html table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, yii2

I have use yii2 for making nested form successfully

now I want go one step further

I use nested form for master-detail system, which use at least 2 table

In tutorial and documentation using wbraganca nested form, there is a plus button when clicked, will add new input for detail row

What I want to achieve:

the detail input appear only once, and the information inputed temporary to one html table via javascript or ajax

so, the data inputed to database is data in temporary html table, not data in input

how can I achieve this?

Thanks before, Any help appreciated, ideas and sample code is very welcome

Comment: Loop through your html table (Using javascript / Jquery) and collect that into JSON object and then pass that data using ajax to server side. Yii controller.

Comment: Share your code here